# Swift: How to access variable element of an enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, openweathermap

For hours I've been struggeling with getting an variable element of an enum.

The "[Swifticons](https://github.com/ranesr/SwiftIcons)" - pod provides me with the following enum:

```
public enum WeatherType: Int {
    static var count: Int {
        return weatherIcons.count
    }

    public var text: String? {
        return weatherIcons[rawValue]
    }

    case alien, barometer, celsius, owm300, owm301, owm302, and200moreOfTheseNames
}

private let weatherIcons = ["\u{f075}", "\u{f079}", and202moreOfTheseFontCharacters]
```

From an external API ([openWeatherMap.org](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5)) I just get an weather code (let's say "300") - and I want to access Icon "owm300".

But how do I access this element of the enum without knowing the rawValue (which would be - say - 198)?

Comment: You may be able to use `CaseIterable` in the future (I [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49371168/251153) to include it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the plan:

1. We need to enumerate all of the enum cases. We'll do that by iterating over raw values (luckily, `WeatherType` is backed by `Int`).
2. We will store lazily initialized dictionary that maps `String` to `WeatherType`.
3. And finally, we declare a static function that returns an optional `WeatherType?` because we can encounter an unknown value.

Here's the code:

```
extension WeatherType {
  // just some little convenience
  private typealias W = WeatherType

  // 1. define the sequence of all cases
  private static func allCases() -> AnySequence<W> {
    return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<W> in
      var raw = 0
      return AnyIterator {
        // Iterates while raw value can be converted to an enum case
        if let next = W(rawValue: raw) {
          raw += 1
          return next
        }
        return nil
      }
    }
  }

  // 2. Static properties are lazy so we'll use them to store the dictionary with String to WeatherType mapping
  private static let typeMap = W.allCases().reduce([String: W]()) { acc, next in
    var acc = acc
    acc[String(describing: next)] = next
    return acc
  }

  // 3. Declare the mapping function
  static func from(string: String) -> WeatherType? {
    return W.typeMap[string]
  }
}
```

Here's a little test:

```
let str = "301"
let type = WeatherType.from(string: "owm\(str)")
print(type == .owm301)
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution! No need to copy&paste the enum's data - that's what I was looking for. Thank you so much!
As I've learned in @zneak's answer, it might get obsolete in Swift 4.2, but in the meantime it will help guys like me :)

Comment: @DanKarbayev, I think this would very much help me. Is this extendable to enums with default associated values? If so, is there some direction on how I would implement it.

My enum looks something like
```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo(value1: Bool = false, value2: Any? = nil)
    case bar(value1: Bool = true, value2: Any? = 5
}
```

Is there a way to conform this to the allCases you mentioned above? All associated value types are the same.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way I can think of is create some kind of mapping dictionary, where you would keep track of weather response code and WeatherType that it maps to like so,

```
let weatherCodeMapping: [Int: WeatherType] = [300: .owm300,
                                              301: .owm301,
                                              302: .owm302]
```

With this in place, you dont need to know any specific rawValue, you can simply get code by,

```
 let weatherType = weatherCodeMapping[weatherCode]
```

And then create some other mapping for your image based on the weatherType.

```
let weatherIcon = weatherIconMapping[weatherType]
```

or create a single mapping directly from weather code to icon.

Comment: I had hoped for a more elegant solution (without copy&paste, as pods may change), but it seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: I'm refering to your "weatherCodeMapping"-dictionary. It's a manual copy&paste from the pod's enum (which contains exactly 590 items). Any changes in the original pod (due to whatever reasons) are not recognized by this new dictionary.
But don't get me wrong: Your answer solved the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't currently have enumerable sequences of enum cases. One option that you have is to copy the [list of icon names](https://github.com/ranesr/SwiftIcons/blob/420ccbddcdf548df43b60715bb3afefe978435dd/SwiftIcons/IconDetailViewController.swift#L155), then search for your icon's name, and use that index as the enum's rawValue:

```
let weatherIcons = [...]
let iconName = "owm300"
let possibleIconIndex = weatherIcons.index {
    $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(iconName) == .orderedSame
}
if let iconIndex = possibleIconIndex {
    let weatherIcon = WeatherIcon(rawValue: iconIndex)!
    // ...
} else {
    // graceful fallback for when the weather icon is missing
}
```

Of course, you need to figure out your own mapping between the data you get from the service and enum names, but that could be as simple as `"owm\(weatherCode)"`.

When Swift 4.2 lands, you will be able to make your enums conform to a new protocol called [`CaseIterable`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0194-derived-collection-of-enum-cases.md). Enums that conform to it get a synthesized implementation of an `allCases` static variable. You will then be able to use that enumeration to build a string-to-enum dictionary automatically:

```
let nameToEnum = WeatherIcon.allCases.map { (String($0), $0) }
let mapping = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: nameToEnum)
```

That will however require `WeatherIcon` to be **declared** with the `CaseEnumerable` conformance, as adding it with an `extension` has no effect.